# Interpretation of a WWII badge of rank(?) / medal

Tags: world-war-two

I found this badge of rank from WWII (probably German/Italian):
[image: badge of rank]
How to interpret the stripes and the star? Which meaning do they have?

Comment: Are you sure those are badges of rank and not medals?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: No, I'm unfortunately not sure. I'm glad for any help.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but you might start [here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/95/c7/aa/95c7aa9d7c2054b483c39a8f92977194.jpg&imgrefurl=https://www.pinterest.com/pin/299700550172399904/&h=2074&w=1507&tbnid=JXQnN88lw3UPEM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=116&usg=__vyXS6g9jKGcC3sHmP0xtv8cHh9k=&vet=10ahUKEwjy_JPD2cTTAhXFSiYKHYMrBqkQ9QEIJjAA..i&docid=M1i_ziwia07K-M&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy_JPD2cTTAhXFSiYKHYMrBqkQ9QEIJjAA)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are [Service Ribbons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_ribbon), which denote which medals a 
soldier has been awarded without having the medals themselves displayed on their uniform.

<s>Yours appears to be from a British or Commonwealth soldier during World War 2.</s> Your ribbons are from a Polish Soldier operating under British Commonwealth Command in Italy during World War 2, possibly as part of the [II Corps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/II_Corps_(Poland)) (found by extrapolating from your username).
The medals these represent (that I have found are),

1. The [War Medal 1939-1945](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Medal_1939%E2%80%931945)
2. The [Italy Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italy_Star)
3. The [1939-1945 Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1939%E2%80%931945_Star) (Reversed)
4. The [Army Medal for War 1939-1945](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_Medal_for_War_1939-45)
5. Possibly the (Italian) [Medal of Military Valor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medal_of_Military_Valor)

I am not certain of the fifth ribbon's identity, but it seems to match, and it is possible that it could have been awarded after September 8th when Italy signed the armistice and joined the Allies.